# Xamarin.Forms.Labs iOS SMS texting issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms.Labs to send SMS messages from my app. It works great on WP and Android but with the iOS it opens up the default texting screen and allows you to send a text but then I am unable to get back to my app. I click cancel or the iPhone button and reopen my app and it is still on the texting screen. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong or why it doesn't return to my app once I have finished texting?  Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the iOS implementation. I just pushed a fix for it and you can use the latest code (master branch) to test it out.

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/pull/498

I will get it included in the next release package.